# How can I simultaneously pass args and upload a file to a Web API Controller Method?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, compact-framework, multipartform-data

I decided that my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995828/how-to-send-xml-in-a-uri-for-posting-to-a-web-api-app) isn't really what I want to do - the XML I need to send is a lot longer, potentially, than I really want to send in a URI.

It didn't "feel" right doing that, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) unsealed the deal.

I need to send both a couple of args AND a file to my Web API app from a client (handheld/CF) app.

I may have found the code for receiving that, from here [
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2]

Specifically, Wasson's Controller code here looks like it very well might work:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Holds the response body

        // Read the form data and return an async task.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // This illustrates how to get the form data.
        foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
        {
            foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", key, val));
            }
        }

        // This illustrates how to get the file names for uploaded files.
        foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
            sb.Append(string.Format("Uploaded file: {0} ({1} bytes)\n", fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length));
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString())
        };
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

...but now I need to know how to send it; other calls from the client are of the form:

```
http://<IPAddress>:<portNum>/api/<ControllerName>?arg1=Bla&arg2=Blee
```

but how does the file I need to send/attach get passed along? It is a XML file, but I don't want to append the whole thing to the URI, as it can be quite large, and doing so would be horrendously weird.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

### UPDATE

Following the crumbs tvanfosson dropped below, I found code [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/) which I think I can adapt to work on the client:

```
var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var filestream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
    content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", fileName);
}

message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
message.Content = content;
message.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:3128/api/uploading/");

var client = new HttpClient();
client.SendAsync(message).ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    { 
        //do something with response
    }
});
```

...but that depends on whether the [Compact Framework supports MultipartFormDataContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024479/how-can-i-determine-which-net-features-the-compact-framework-has)

### UPDATE 2

Which it doesn't, according to [How can i determine which .Net features the compact framework has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024479/how-can-i-determine-which-net-features-the-compact-framework-has/22024502?noredirect=1#comment33387529_22024502)

### UPDATE 3

Using the Bing Search Code for C# extension, I mashed "h", chose "How do I", entered "send file via http" and got this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

As I need to add a couple of string args in addition to the file (which I assume I can add via the postData byte array), can I do that by adding more calls to dataStream.Write()? IOW, is this sensible (first and third lines differ):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://MachineName:NNNN/api/Bla?str1=Blee&str2=Bloo");
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = //open the HTML file and assign its contents to this, or make it File postData instead of string postData?
// the rest is the same
```

?

### UPDATE 4

Progress: This, such as it is, is working:

Server code:

```
public string PostArgsAndFile([FromBody] string value, string serialNum, string siteNum)
{
    string s = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", value, serialNum, siteNum);
    return s;
}
```

Client code (from Darin Dimitrov in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771032/post-string-to-asp-net-web-api-application-returns-null)):

```
private void ProcessRESTPostFileData(string uri)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var data = "=Short test...";
        var result = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", data);
        //try this: var result = client.UploadFile(uri, "bla.txt");
        //var result = client.UploadData()
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
}
```

Now I need to get it sending a file instead of a string in the [FromBody] arg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using multipart/form-data with a custom media type formatter that will extract both the string properties and the uploaded XML file.

http://lonetechie.com/2012/09/23/web-api-generic-mediatypeformatter-for-file-upload/