# How can i determine which .Net features the compact framework has?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, multipartform-data

I need to know which classes/types the compact framework supports.

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172548%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but it doesn't seem to help much.

Specifically, I need to know if CF supports MultipartFormDataContent, as I need to upload a file from a handheld device to a Web API app.

Does anybody know of a source that shows which classes/types are available in CF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN shows this information. If you go to a page, for example a class, and select the .NET 3.5 version of it, the members of the class will have a PDA icon if it is supported in the CF.

edit:

That class appears to be .NET 4.5+

**Version Information**
.NET Framework
Supported in: 4.5.1, 4.5
.NET for Windows Store apps
Supported in: Windows 8

Compare that to the [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class for example

Comment: Yeah (dang it!): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Welcome to the CF. A lot of stuff is missing from the regular framework, especially .NET 4.0+. .NET 3.5 CF vs full is about 25% if I recall correctly. You usually have to look into implementing things yourself, p/invoke windows APIs, or 3rd party libs.